# style-loader stopped working after updating "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8, webpack-style-loader

To load my style dynamically with *Angular 8*, I use the below code which works fine. But then, updating the package `"@angular-deficit/build-angular": "^0. 800.0"` to `"@angular-deficit/build-angular": "^0. 803.21"` breaks my setup, meaning everything in the application works as expected except that style is not applied anymore.

```js
declare function require(name: string): any;
    ngOnInit() {
        require('style-loader!./file-path');
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "latest-frontend-theme",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.8",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.6",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng6-toastr": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.12.21",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciable.

Comment: could you please post `package.json`?

Comment: I have updated the question and post the package.json file.

Comment: First try 2 things, stop angular application, exit vs code then start vs code and again run angular application. After that please update here.

Comment: Can you please explain what is "vs code"?

Comment: What is your IDE, i assumed it is visual studio code?

Comment: I have already done this multiple time but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today and was still unable to find a solution using `style-loader` so I came up with an alternate solution that I'll share since this is still unanswered.

I was previously using `style-loader` like this:

```js
// in the AppComponent
private initTheme(settings: Settings) {

  if (settings.style) {
    // set specific theme 
    require(`style-loader!./../../src/${settings.style.id}-theme.scss`);
  }
  else {
    require(`style-loader!./../../src/default-theme.scss`);
  }
}
```

My solution was to update this function to apply the style sheet (as a processed CSS file) manually, like this:

```js
// in the AppComponent
private initTheme(settings: Settings) {

  const applyStyleSheet = (styleName: string) => {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const style = document.createElement('link');
    style.rel = 'stylesheet';
    style.href = `${styleName}.css`;
    head.appendChild(style);
  };

    if (settings.style) {
      // set specific theme
      applyStyleSheet(`${settings.style.id}-theme`);
    }
    else {
      applyStyleSheet(`default-theme`);
    }
  }
```

In order to have the SCSS files processed i changed my `angular.json` file, adding `extractCss` to the options:

```json
"options": {
  "extractCss": true
  ...
}
```

... and specifying each SCSS file in the `styles` array to be processed, but not injected:

```json
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/default-theme.scss",
    "bundleName": "default-theme",
    "inject": false
  },
  {
    "input": "src/basic-theme.scss",
    "bundleName": "basic-theme",
    "inject": false
  }
  ...
]
```